# How do I strace tomcat server?

Tags: java, tomcat, tomcat8, strace

To strace I need a pid but I am not able to get any pids by running

> pidof tomcat or pgrep tomcat

If we check its status via systemctl we see main PID but its name is java. Do we need to strace java in order to strace that application? I donn't think so.
result of

> *systemctl status tomcat*
>
> tomcat.service - Apache Tomcat Web Application Container    Loaded:
>   loaded (/etc/systemd/system/tomcat.service; enabled; vendor preset:
>   enabled)    Active: active (running) since Sat 2018-09-29 16:10:45
>   PKT; 1h 1min ago   Process: 9618 ExecStop=/opt/tomcat/bin/shutdown.sh
>   (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)   Process: 14493
>   ExecStart=/opt/tomcat/bin/startup.sh (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS) 
>   Main PID: 14531 (java)
>       Tasks: 50 (limit: 4915)    CGroup: /system.slice/tomcat.service
>              └─14531 /usr/lib/jvm/java-1.11.0-openjdk-amd64/bin/java -Djava.util.logging.config.file=/opt/tomcat/conf/logging.properties -Djav

Comment: I am doing some testing. I have written a kprobe kernel module that get the name of a software and then monitor it for any futex call it makes and eventually kill that call.  I need to get the pid and its name. Please help me in this manner.

Comment: The process you want to strace probably is `14531 /usr/lib/jvm/java-1.11.0-openjdk-amd64/bin/java ...`

Comment: @ThomasFritsch yes this is the process but when I strace this it show like it only strace java and promt me with this
.....
strace: Process 18489 attached
strace: Process 18490 attached
Usage: java [options] <mainclass> [args...]
           (to execute a class)
   or  java [options] -jar <jarfile> [args...]
           (to execute a jar file)
   or  java [options] -m <module>[/<mainclass>] [args...]
       java [options] --module <module>[/<mainclass>] [args...]
           (to execute the main class in a module)
.... etc

Answer (score 0):

> Tomcat is written in Java so it will be a java process.

Below command will strace tomcat service when run as root or any user having appropriate sudo permissions.

```
strace -p `ps aux|grep -v grep|grep tomcat|awk '{print $2}'|head -n1`
```

[image]

[image]

This test has been performed on a personal Test VM as ROOT and would suggest NOT to use it on PRODUCTION.

Hope this helps to some extent.

Comment: in your case if you find the name of process 762 by this "ps -p 762 -o comm=" would you get java or tomcat?
As in my case the pid that your command gives is of JAVA

Comment: Since tomcat is a java based application it is started using java binary. So always ps will show it as a java process. Can you let me know what exactly do you need to accomplish?

Comment: Worth mentioning that even when you install application servers like websphere or weblogic they too are java programs so linux will identify them as java process only because thats how java virtual machines are identified. Although in server.xml of websphere there is an option to change the executable name to whatever you like which is java by default. I dont know if that can be achieved in tomcat.

Comment: Thank you for your help good person. What I need to accomplish is that I have written a kernel module which monitors futex calls from a specific software and kill them. I need to load (insmod) that module with the name of that software in arguments e.g firefox, chrome, postgres etc . In this case I can't find the name other than java.